# UIBezierPath on UiView doesn't update until scroll the tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have added UIView to cell of Tableview and given the beizer path to bottom and right by following:

```
UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0,
                          0,
                          cell.bgView.frame.size.width -2+ shadowSize,
                          cell.bgView.frame.size.height+1 + shadowSize)];
    cell.bgView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    cell.bgView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:186.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:231.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f]CGColor];
    cell.bgView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
    cell.bgView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
    cell.bgView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
```

First time, when tableview reload, bezier path doesn't load properly

[image: See Picture 1]

but when I scroll up/down then it looks perfectly

[image: See Picture 2].

I have tried with every possible solution i.e.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.topRatedTable reloadData];
            });
```

or

```
 [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
```

But nothing works.

Answer (score 3):

Your cell and its subviews (like, I assume, `bgView`) don't have their final frames until layout has run. If your path-creating code is in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, then you are accessing `cell.bgView.frame` before layout has run.

In your custom `UITableViewCell` subclass, override `layoutSubviews` and set the `shadowPath` after calling `super`:

```
// In your custom `UITableViewCell` subclass:
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0,
                      0,
                      cell.bgView.frame.size.width -2+ shadowSize,
                      cell.bgView.frame.size.height+1 + shadowSize)];
    self.bgView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        // UIBezierPath job
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it bad to override a UITableViewCell's drawing function?

Comment: @CaMenz : yes its not a best of the practice to do other coding on drawRect but in case of UIBezierPath, it is where we normally draw things.